# Prevent Close without Save of Iframe in Modal

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I have a project to not allow a form to be closed unless the user saves their changes first. The way the page is set up having the parent page, cshtml, to have a modal and inside that modal is an Iframe that has the form, html. I tried just editing the form to have a beforeunload eventlistner however the that does not work since the Iframe can only be hidden not closed. I am currently trying to connect the parent and child up to talk to each other by having:
parent.cshtml

```
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="width:100%; height:75%;">
                <div id="complianceIframeBody" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    <iframe id="IframeHtml" class="iframe;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src=""></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="closeBtn" class="btnOk btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

```
    <script>
        function preventNaigation() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                return "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page ? Any unsaved changes will be lost.";
            }
        }
</script>
```

child.html

```
<script>
    $("#form0 :input").change(function () {
        preventNavigation();
        });
</script>
```

My question is how cna I have these two communicate in order for the Iframe to prompt the User they are leaving unsaved changes when they click a close button on the modal.